# How to wait for an authentication related Promise to resolve?

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm creating a React app with Firebase authentication. After a successful login, I'm querying a user document in a Firestore database to request the full name of the logged in user.

This full name is used in several parts of the app. However, those components sometimes get rendered before the authentication completes, thus leaving the full name to be 'undefined'.

What is the usual practice is such a case? Should I check if full name is not 'undefined' in all places where I use it? Or is there a way to have the app wait until the full authentication process finishes (including the Firestore query) and only then render the components?

**AuthContext**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      // user is logged in
      setCurrentUser(user);
      const userDataPromise = await getUserData(user);
      setUserData(userDataPromise);
    } else {
      // user is logged out
      setCurrentUser(null);
      setUserData(null);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider
    value={{
      currentUser,
      userData,
    }}
  >
    {loading ? <LinearProgress /> : children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

**getUserData:**

```
export default async function getUserData(currentUser) {
  if (currentUser) {
    // Get user
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid);
    const userSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
    if (!userSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("No user data found in the database.");
      return null;
    } else {
      const userData = userSnap.data();
      // some additional querying...
      return userData;
    }
  } else {
    console.warning("User not logged in");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the usual practice is such a case? Should I check if fullName
> is not 'undefined' in all places where I use it? Or is there a way to
> have the app wait until the full authentication process finishes
> (including the Firestore query) and only then render the components?

All interactions between your web application and the Firebase back-end services are asynchronous operations (and the corresponding methods in the JS SDKs return [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)).

**You therefore need to deal with this aspect in your application**. For example showing a spinner until the call(s) to Firestore is(are) completed (i.e. until the Promise returned by the call to the Firestore method, e.g. `getDoc()`, is fulfilled or rejected in case of error).

*(Ready to help further if you share some code)*

Comment: Thank you Renaud. I've added the relevant code. I'm looking for a way to show the <LinearProgress /> until both setCurrentUser and setUserData are finished. Perhaps something like 

{loading || !currentUser || !userData ? <LinearProgress /> : children}

?

Comment: Yes you need to use [conditional rendering](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) based on some boolean that you modify when the asynchronous operations are completed.